# How to get the foreignkey details of a foreignkey in a table in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have 3 tables like table1,table2 and table3,here table 2 is child of table 1 and table 3 is child of table2, when i query on table3 i want to get the foreignkey details table2 and table1.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the official sqlalchemy documentation? It's easier to help you if your problem is more precise and if at least there is a code that you tried!

Comment: I don't know how to do that so posted a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent tutorial on databases with Flask-sqlAlchemy [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database).

The simplest idea, if I understood your question correctly, is to make a two-part request. First you find a specific info in table1, then you link it to the second query to find information in table2 or eventually table3.

Concretely, suppose it is a blog. You have two tables: your table1 contains all the users (table1=Users) and the table2 contains the publications of the users (table2=Posts). There is a foreign key that links the two tables. Now you would like to see all posts for user 'John'. What you do is start by finding the user John, then you look for all the posts related to him:

```
>>> user = Users.query.filter_by(username='John').first()
>>> posts = user.Posts.all()
```